# ReactPHP listen on TCP port

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I am able to read data from server with `nc`:

```
nc -vvl -p 1234
Listening on any address 1234 (search-agent)
Connection from 192.168.1.11:56929
24203   24204   24205   24206   24207   ^CExiting.
Total received bytes: 30
Total sent bytes: 0
```

I am failing to do the same via ReactPHP:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use React\Socket\ConnectionInterface;

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new React\Socket\TcpConnector($loop);

$connector->connect('1234')->then(function (ConnectionInterface $conn) use ($loop) {
    $conn->pipe(new React\Stream\WritableResourceStream(STDOUT, $loop));
    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn) {
        echo $data;
    });    
});

$loop->run();
```

Running `php file.php` terminates instantly, without any output. I want it to stay running and printing what it receives, the same way as with `nc`. Can somene forward me to the right direction, please? Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in your php log?

Comment: My errors are accessible via journalctl through syslog-ng. No relevant info in `journalctl | grep php`, nor `journalctl $(which php)`, nor `journalctl -u nginx.service -u php-fpm.service` unfortunately.